# Can an ASP.NET Web.Config file have a dynamic value?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config

Not really sure if i'm asking this correctly or not,  but can a web.config file have a data driven value.?  For example,  in my mailSettings section,  i have this

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <network host="11.222.33.4" userName="MyUsername"  />                        
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

i would like the host="11.222.33.44" to come from a database..   Is this possible.?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the SMTP configuration from web.config file. I don't think there can be a dynamic variable in web.config file

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
string host = smtp.Host; // you will get the host value here. Then update the host value here with the database host value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could ignore web.config altogether and create an smtp client on the fly. Get your value from a database however you like then

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient c = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(< host name or ip address >);
c.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

Comment: P.S. if you need to actually update the web.config file you can do that. That question has been answered on this site.